# Curved spacetime at high energy

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

It's said that at high energy general relativity stops predicting. I don't care about renormalization but my question is different.
We have the "energy-stress tensor" and from measuring energy/mass and momentum thanks to the Einstein field equation we come to the values of the terms of the Ricci tensor.

1. At high energy the Einstein equation "is still valid", but not for energy and momentum, right?
2. I mean that the Ricci tensor still exists but we cannot find it because energy and momentum are no more related to the Ricci tensor, they are related just for low energy ?

Comment: General relativity stops predicting at high energies because it is a classical theory, and one needs quantum theory in order to fully describe space-time at small distances.

Comment: at high energy Einstein equations may not be valid, at some point a more fundamental theory is expected to modify them

Comment: my question remains: "At high energy the Einstein equation "is still valid", but not for energy and momentum, right?"